# A generalization of this type of mean to power > 2

Tags: calculus, inequality, means

Let $a,b \in (0, \infty)$ and $0 < \theta < 1$. Then
$$
(a + b)^2 \leq \frac{1}{\theta} a^2 + \frac{1}{1 - \theta} b^2.
$$

Can you generalize to a power $m \geq 2$?

(The question is not whether the inequality holds with $2$ replaced by $m$.)

Comment: @thosewhovoteforclose: inspecting the answers and the comments given, it should be clear what is being asked here.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can generalise using Holder's inequality that:
$$\left(\frac1\theta a^m + \frac1{1-\theta}b^m\right)(\theta+\overline{1-\theta})(1+1)^{m-2} \ge (a+b)^m \implies \frac1\theta a^m + \frac1{1-\theta}b^m \ge \frac{(a+b)^m}{2^{m-2}}$$

Comment: what's $\overline{1-\theta}$?

Comment: Just a convention to evaluate that first, same as $(1-\theta)$.

Answer (score 3):

This is a different generalization:
$$
(a+b)^m\le\frac{1}{\theta^{m-1}}\,a^m+\frac{1}{(1-\theta)^{m-1}}\,b^m.
$$
It follows from the inequality
$$
(1+x)^m\le\frac{1}{\theta^{m-1}}+\frac{1}{(1-\theta)^{m-1}}\,x^m,\quad0<x<1.
$$
To prove it, minimize for $x$ fixed as a function of $\theta$ the right hand side. The minimum is attained at $\theta=1/(1+x)$ and its value is precisely $(1+x)^m$.

Comment: Yes, this is the kind of generalization I was looking for; however, Macavity's answer has already helped obtaining it (one can also use Hoelder inequality to prove yours).

Comment: Nice +1. Just for completeness, using Holder we can combine the two generalisations, for $2 \le n \le m$:
$$\frac{a^m}{\theta^n} + \frac{b^m}{(1-\theta)^n} \ge \frac{(a+b)^m}{2^{m-n-1}}$$
Equality is when $a=b=1, \; \theta=\frac12$.

Comment: @Macavity I think that $n,m$ generalization merits inclusion into an answer.

Comment: @becko not really sure if that would add much value, but anyway done. Though I won't remove the above comment as that generalisation is inspired by Julian's post.

Answer (score 2):

Just for completeness, combining the two generalisations we have, for $2 \le n \le m$ we can show by Holder's inequality:
$$\left( \frac{a^m}{\theta^n} + \frac{b^m}{(1-\theta)^n}  \right)(\theta  +\overline{1-\theta})^n(1+1)^{m-n-1} \ge (a+b)^m$$

$$\implies \frac{a^m}{\theta^n} + \frac{b^m}{(1-\theta)^n} \ge \frac{(a+b)^m}{2^{m-n-1}}$$
Equality is when $a=b=1, \; \theta=\frac12$.